# How to show that $(T^*)^{-1}$ is the same as $(T^{-1})^*$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This is the same as show that if $T$ is an invertible operator and the inverse is $T^{-1}$, then the inverse of the adjoint of $T$ is the adjoint of the inverse of $T$.

I really have no clue at all. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Can you give more details? Is $T$ a linear operator between Banach spaces? Hilbert spaces? Or something else? And $T^*$ is the adjoint in what sense?

Comment: Well, $I=I^*=(T^{-1}T)^*$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It's sufficient to prove that $(T^{-1})^*$ is an inverse of $T^*$.